# What is the material of this tow bar?

Tags: towing

What are the materials used in a tow bar of the pictured design? I am interested in the materials use for the tube (which aluminium alloy?) and the materials of the lunette mount flat and inside structure. [image]

Comment: Have you tried asking the manufacturer?

Comment: I'm looking forward to the answer. My gut instinct is that material choice is not particularly sensitive because the application requires stiffness as the priority.  Typically, when stiffness is the goal, strength comes naturally. But typical != always.

Comment: Barium, of course.

Answer (score 2):

> Aircraft towbars are almost exclusively aircraft-grade aluminum or
>   steel in construction  to meet or exceed the working load. Not only
>   must the towbar be able to safely pull/push the vehicle, it must also
>   be able to withstand the towed vehicle's inertia.

[Source](https://www.globalspec.com/learnmore/specialized_industrial_products/towbars)

Although there are several components that make up the tow bar they all must be strong enough to withstand the forces exerted on them. That's what the label on your picture is for, it dictates what aircraft you can use the tow bar on. Larger aircraft = Larger more robust tow bar.